# Place image in highchart pie chart like linkedIn

Tags: ajax, highcharts

I need help trying to achieve the first in the second image. Not the monocolor because the image and the text in the middle.

[image: First Image - from linkedIn]

[image: Second image - mine]

Answer (score 0):

You can use a renderer which allows to add custom image / text anywhere.

```
chart.renderer.image('http://highcharts.com/demo/gfx/sun.png', 100, 100, 30, 30)
        .add();
```

> image (String source, Number x, Number y, Number width, Number height)Since 2.0 Add an image from an external resource.
>
> Parameters
>
> source: String The URL of the image. x: String The x position of the
>   image's upper left corner. y: String The y position of the image's
>   upper left corner. width: String The width of the image. height:
>   String The height of the image.